# Straight line grid cell path smoothing in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, navigation, ros

I'm building a navigation node in ROS.
I'm new to ROS and Python (2.7).
I have a grid cell from which I get the shortest path (in cell coordinates) between two cells (start to goal).

My question is:
What will be a fast elegant way to smooth my path?

a smooth path means that if my moving direction does not change between two cells, I can omit all the cells between these cells.

I mean, for example if my path is `(x,y):[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)]`

My smooth path should be:
`[(1,1),(1,3),(2,3),(2,5)]`

*Notice that for example between `(1,1)` and `(1,3)` the direction does not change, so we drop `(1,2)`.*

Comment: Is numpy an option?

Comment: Yes, I can use whatever I want.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be rephrased as: for each coordinate, if the next coordinate right behind it from the previous, remove it.

I'm assuming 'moving direction does not change' means that: if you were to draw a line through the first two points, the third would be behind the second point from the first point, on the same line.

So, `[(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]` becomes `[(1,1), (3,3)]` and `[(1,1), (3,2), (5,3)]` becomes `[(1,1), (5,3)]`.

```
path = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]


def behind(x, y, z):
    # if the first two points are on a vertical line
    if x[0] == y[0]:
        # if the third point is one the same vertical line?
        if y[0] == z[0]:
            # then they still need to be in the correct order
            return x[1] > y[1] > z[1] or x[1] < y[1] < z[1]
        else:
            return False
    elif y[0] == z[0]:
        return False
    # none of the points are directly above each other, calculate and compare direction
    return (x[1] - y[1]) / (x[0] - y[0]) == (y[1] - z[1]) / (y[0] - z[0])


triples = list(zip(path[:-2], path[1:-1], path[2:]))
smooth_path = path[:1] + [
    y for x, y, z in triples
    if not behind(x, y, z)
] + path[-1:]

print(smooth_path)
```

The first and last coordinate are always in, for the rest, this example generates a set of triples with each other coordinate in the middle and then checks for each of them if they line up perfectly - if so, it does not include the coordinate, otherwise it does include it.

Answer (score 0):

Given three points `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)]`, the middle point `(x2, y2)` can be removed if the slopes of the successive line segments are the same. I.e., if `(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) == (y3 - y2) / (x3 - x2)`. To avoid the possibility of dividing by zero and to eliminate any roundoff error, the condition to eliminate the middle point can be cross-multiplied to `(x3 - x2) * (y2 - y1) == (x2 - x1) * (y3 - y2)`.

Let's say you have a numpy array as your path:

```
path = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
path = np.array(path)
```

You can compute the retention mask as follows:

```
delta = np.diff(path, axis=0)
prod = delta[:-1, :] * delta[1:, ::-1]
```

`diff` is a two column vector of `(x2 - x1), (y2 - y1)`. `prod` then becomes a two column vector containing the components of the elimination condition. You can make a mask of it:

```
mask = (prod[:, 0] != prod[:, 1])
```

And apply the mask:

```
smoothed = np.concatenate((
    path[np.newaxis, 0, :],
    path[1:-1, :][mask, :],
    path[np.newaxis, -1, :]), axis=0)
```

The concatenation is necessary because the mask contains `len(path) - 2` elements, as you would expect. The endpoints are guaranteed to be present in the output. So you end up having to concatenate the first row, the masked portion, and the last row. Inserting `np.newaxis` into the index ensures that the row slices come out 2D row vectors rather than 1D arrays.

The result is

```
 [[1 1]
  [1 3]
  [2 3]
  [2 5]]
```

Here is an IDEOne link with a demo: https://ideone.com/rykLCz

If you need to convert back to a list:

```
smoothed = list(map(tuple, smoothed))
```

Comment: I need the output to be a list of 2 element tuples, and I could not get that from your answer, which seems to be correct when I ran my tests.
Could you please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why it needs to be two element tuples specifically?

Comment: The numpy array offers the same indexing and iteration properties as a list of tuples, but is also faster and generally easier to use. That being said, see my update.